# Paypal GetUserinfo (Identity) only returning user_id

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using PHP to get user information from paypal identity API, but unfortunately i only get user_id in response. I need email and payer_id in response. I have read the documentation , according to that i am supposed to receive multiple parameters in response,  but i am receiving only user_id. I have enabled all the scopes in App permissions. here is the documentation [getuserinfo](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/identity/#openidconnect_userinfo).

here is my code to get user info (I am passing $access_token into this function). I am using sandbox credentials.

```
$api_url = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token/userinfo?schema=openid';//sandbox
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token, 'Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
//dd($data);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($http_code == 200)
return $data;
else if($http_code == 404)
return false;
else
return false;
```

my response :

```
array:1 [▼  "user_id" => "https://www.paypal.com/webapps/auth/identity/user/HdoaS1nMgR_Ltt5mBTv4mRvC9P1wUrWt2NlOVH2e_3w"]
```

Comment: I think this is returning your app as the user. Because The API is meant to be used when you are using [Login with paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/) and I assume you are not using that?

Comment: yes i am using Paypal login . (Paypal identity api)  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/identity/#openidconnect_userinfo

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/219390b7932a4000a1b7d90cc54b52569dd66f22/sample/lipp/GetUserInfo.php#L27, can you pass `access_token` also as a param and try?

Comment: yes i am getting access token and passing that too in request.

Comment: I can't see that in your code?

Comment: third curl_setopt.       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token, 'Content-Type: application/json'));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168401/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-gaurav-malik).

Comment: Why don't you use the [PayPal PHP SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK)? However, if you insist on rewriting PHP code, [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/8d157c3233a270c168389ebbe96729d2dc3cb1d1/lib/PayPal/Api/OpenIdUserinfo.php#L511) you can see how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely your issue: "The attributes returned depend on the scopes configured for the REST app"

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/sandbox-testing/configuring-accounts/#create-a-rest-application

Log In with PayPal. When you enable Log In with PayPal, click Advanced Options and select Personal Information and Address Information, which are disabled by default.

Comment: Thanks for reply , I have enabled all the scope for my application.